# Portable tray-only RSS feed notification

Tags: windows, portable, rss

I am looking for a tiny RSS feed reader that lives as a Windows icon.

When there is a new item, it pops up a notification.

Clicking the icon shows a list of recent items.

Clicking on an item opens your web browser at the URL of the item.

Requirements:

- [Portable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application) (no need to install & can be used with no admin rights)
- Runs on Windows 7 and later

As an example, [Feedindicator](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Feedindicator) is a similar program, but for Ubuntu:

[image: Feedindicator]

*Feedindicator supports multiple feeds, but this is not a requirement here, single-feed is OK.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [QuiteRSS](http://quiterss.org/en)

QuiteRSS is an open-source cross-platform RSS feed reader. Among its features:

- Portable on Windows [[Download link](http://quiterss.org/files/0.17.6/QuiteRSS-0.17.6.zip)]
- Minimizes to tray icon [image]
- Configuralble notifications, with pop-ups, sounds, and custom duration
- Can be configured to show recent feeds on single click (default behavior is on double clicking the tray icon)
- Clicking on a feed opens the page in the embedded browser. Clicking a toolbar icon, or using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> opens it in the external browser.